# How do I animate CATransform3Ds with a CAKeyframeAnimation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-animation

I've used CAKeyframeAnimations to animate a layer's `transform.rotation` and `transform.translation.x` properties, but I'm having trouble animating the `transform` property implicitly. I have a layer that must animate between two states and CABasicAnimation's default interpolation is totally incorrect and doesn't follow the path I want. CAKeyframeAnimation to the rescue, or so I thought. Any attempt to animate `transform` using a CAKeyframeAnimation results in the view immediately snapping to the final transform while the other animations run. If I remove the first half of the following function and let my "transform" events use the CABasicAnimation on the bottom, it animates just fine - albeit with incorrectly interpolated transforms along the way.

My layer delegate has implemented the following:

```
- (id <CAAction>) actionForLayer:(CALayer *)layer forKey:(NSString *)event
{    
    if ([event isEqualToString:@"transform"])
    {
        CGSize startSize = ((CALayer *)self.layer.presentationLayer).bounds.size;
        CGSize endSize = self.layer.bounds.size;

        CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:event];
        animation.duration = 0.25;

        NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray array];

        int stepCount = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < stepCount; i++)
        {
            CGFloat p = i / (float)(stepCount - 1);
            CGSize size = [self interpolateBetweenSize:startSize andSize:endSize percentage:p];
            CATransform3D transform = [self transformForSize:size];
            [values addObject:[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform]];
        }

        animation.values = values;
        return animation;
    }

    // All other animations use this basic animation
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:event];
    animation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    animation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
    animation.duration = 0.25;
    return animation;
}
```

My transform is a translation followed by a rotate, but I think a group animation with separate keyframe animations animating through a translation AND a rotate would result in crazy town. I've confirmed that size & transform are correct for all values of p that I pass though, and p strictly ranges from 0 to 1.

I've tried setting a non-default timing function, I've tried setting an array of timing functions, I've omitted the keyTImes, I've set a repeatCount of 0, removedOnCompletion=YES, and a fillMode of forwards and that had no effect. Am I not creating the transform keyframe animation correctly?

Comment: Could you perhaps clarify the exact effect you are trying to achieve? You describe it as a translation followed by a rotation, but from your code it looks like the bounds are also animating - is that correct? You want the layer to move, then rotate, with the bounds growing or shrinking continuously throughout both phases of the move/rotate animation?

Comment: Why does it need to be implicit? This code looks hacky. If you want fine grained control why not just create the animation and add it directly to the layer, which you say you have working already? Also just return `nil` from that delegate method if you want things to use their default animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This technique worked back in iOS 3 but seemed to be broken in iOS 5.0.

5.1 'magically' fixed this, it seemed to be a bug in iOS 5.0. I'd file a radar, but it is now working in 5.1.

@Gsnyder: Some background: I am experimenting with Clear-like UI (for something completely unrelated to Clear) and came up with this: http://blog.massivehealth.com/post/18563684407/clear. That should explain the need for a rotate & translate.

I've since created a shutter transition that subdivides a view into N layers (instead of just 2) that looks like this when viewed from the side: /////.

My code is not animating the bounds, it is using the size at each step to determine the necessary transform.

@Paul.s: Implicit allows me to keep this abstraction within the layer class itself without polluting the view controller that owns it. The view controller should just be changing the bounds around and the layer should move appropriately. I'm not a fan of view controllers having dozens of custom animations when the views themselves can handle it.

I need to use a keyframe animation because the default animation between layer transforms  / and _ animate through incorrect  angles so the ///\ layers do not line up throughout the transform. The keyframe animations ensure the edges all line up correctly while they all animate.

I'm considering this closed, this seems to be a bug in iOS 5.0 and has since been fixed. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
(void)animateViewWith3DCurrentView:(UIView *)currentView withPoing:(CGPoint)movePoint
{
    //flip the view by 180 degrees in its place first.
    currentView.layer.transform =          CATransform3DRotate(currentView.layer.transform,myRotationAngle(180), 0, 1, 0);

    //set the anchor point so that the view rotates on one of its sides.
    currentView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

    //Set up scaling

    CABasicAnimation *resizeAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:kResizeKey];

    //we are going to fill the screen here. So 423,337
    [resizeAnimation setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGSize:CGSizeMake(423, 337)]];
    resizeAnimation.fillMode            = kCAFillModeForwards;
    resizeAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

     // Set up path movement

    UIBezierPath *movePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    //the control point is now set to centre of the filled screen. Change this to make the path different.
    // CGPoint ctlPoint       = CGPointMake(0.0, 0.5);
    CGPoint ctlPoint       = CGPointMake(1024/2, 768/2);

    //This is the starting point of the animation. This should ideally be a function of the frame of the view to be animated. Hardcoded here.

    // Set here to get the accurate point..
    [movePath moveToPoint:movePoint];

    //The anchor point is going to end up here at the end of the animation.
    [movePath addQuadCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(1024/2, 768/2) controlPoint:ctlPoint];

    CAKeyframeAnimation *moveAnim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:kPathMovement];

    moveAnim.path                = movePath.CGPath;
    moveAnim.removedOnCompletion = YES;

     // Setup rotation animation

    CABasicAnimation* rotateAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:kRotation];
    //start from 180 degrees (done in 1st line)
    CATransform3D fromTransform       = CATransform3DMakeRotation(myRotationAngle(180), 0, 1, 0);
    //come back to 0 degrees
    CATransform3D toTransform         = CATransform3DMakeRotation(myRotationAngle(0), 0, 1, 0);

    //This is done to get some perspective.
    CATransform3D persp1 = CATransform3DIdentity;
    persp1.m34 = 1.0 / -3000;

    fromTransform = CATransform3DConcat(fromTransform, persp1);
    toTransform = CATransform3DConcat(toTransform,persp1);

    rotateAnimation.toValue             = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:toTransform];
    rotateAnimation.fromValue           = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:fromTransform];
    //rotateAnimation.duration            = 2;
    rotateAnimation.fillMode            = kCAFillModeForwards;
    rotateAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;


     // Setup and add all animations to the group

    CAAnimationGroup *group = [CAAnimationGroup animation]; 

    [group setAnimations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:moveAnim,rotateAnimation, resizeAnimation, nil]];

    group.fillMode            = kCAFillModeForwards;
    group.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    group.duration            = 0.7f;
    group.delegate            = self;

    [group setValue:currentView forKey:kGroupAnimation];

    [currentView.layer addAnimation:group forKey:kLayerAnimation];   
}
```